# Load data from table into apex_util.select_list multiple

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

I have a Classic Report with a schedule for each day. There are no, one or multiple entries per day. It looks like this:

```
select 
week_no,
apex_item.DISPLAY_AND_SAVE(p_idx => 8, p_value => plan_id) as ID,
apex_item.select_list(p_idx => 1, p_list_values => 'S1;1,S2;2,S3;3', p_attributes => 'size="3" multiple="multiple"', p_show_null => 'NO', p_show_extra => 'NO', p_item_id => plan_id || '_1', p_value => monday) as monday,
apex_item.select_list(p_idx => 2, p_list_values => 'S1;1,S2;2,S3;3', p_attributes => 'size="3" multiple="multiple"', p_show_null => 'NO', p_show_extra => 'NO', p_item_id => plan_id || '_2', p_value => tuesday) as tuesday,
apex_item.select_list(p_idx => 3, p_list_values => 'S1;1,S2;2,S3;3', p_attributes => 'size="3" multiple="multiple"', p_show_null => 'NO', p_show_extra => 'NO', p_item_id => plan_id || '_3', p_value => wednesday) as wednesday
from plan;
```

I can select multiple values and can save them to my table. It gets save like this "1,2". But I can't load the data rows with multiple selected values.
[image: multi select fields and raw data from table]

I can select multiple options with jQuery like this

```
$('#1000_1').val(["1","2"]);
```

but I don't know how to select the stored values from table with PL/SQL and then set the options selected with javascript.

I tried to load the data in an apex_item.text (id="1000_11" for monday etc.) and transfer the values in "After Refresh" DA to select list like that:

```js
var sel_opt = $('#1000_11').val();

if (sel_opt == "1,2")
{
    $('#1000_1').val(["1","2"]);  
}  
else if (sel_opt == "1,3")
{
    $('#1000_1').val(["1","3"]);    
}
else if (sel_opt == "2,3")
{
    $('#1000_1').val(["2","3"]);    
}
else if (sel_opt == "1,2,3")
{
    $('#1000_1').val(["1","2","3"]);    
}
```

It works, but maybe there's a smarter solution?

I create a sample Workspace on https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1:0:::::

- Workspace: multi_select
- Username: dev
- Password: newYears3problems

Comment: apex link is broken

Comment: apex link fixed

Answer (score 0):

I would create SELECT LIST page items for each selection menu and set their multi selection option to Yes.

[image]

then I'm guessing I'd need something like this somewhere at my page-process section

```
declare
    array apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
begin
    array := apex_util.string_to_table (:P30_SELECT_LIST_1);
    apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection ('P30_SELECT_LIST_1');
    apex_collection.add_members ('P30_SELECT_LIST_1', array);
end;
```

to store more than one menu item at once.

then I'd add something like that to my query

```
and ITEM_1 in (
                select c001 
                from  apex_collections 
                where collection_name = 'P30_SELECT_LIST_1'
                )
```

I probably didn't understand your question, but according to part that I get, it's straightforward sql query. no need for js.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I simplified the problem in my question. There are several parameters on which the report depends. The number of rows change when I change parameters. There can be up to 25 rows. That's why I use apex_item.select_list. For example for every week no. there are a lot of parts on the schedule and the parts, part_ids and number of parts depends on the chosen equipement. For every combination of week_no and part_id there is a plan_id to identify the row in the schedule